# OnePlus 3 - 2G (GSM) network not working - Selected network (o2 - cz) unavailable

Tags: connection-issues, gsm, 2g, oxygenos

I have a weird Issue with my brand new Oneplus 3. It's not connecting to 2G network, or it connects, but calling/data does not work.

- when switching from 3G to 2G, it registers to network, even shows Edge sign, but calling and data is not working
- when switching from 4G to 2G, it even does not connect
  It can be seen on a video I made - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPlk8EEQsPE

What I have tried:

- 5 SIM cards from 3 different operators. All have the same problem, except T-Mobile, which was able to make a call once in +-10 attempts
- flashing various versions of Oxygen OS (3.1.x, latest 3.2.7); flashing CyanogenMod latest; eflashed whole phone by Oneplus support using MSMDownloadTool
- hard resets, *#*#4626#*#* menu settings etc...

Nothing works. Could not find anywhere on the internet much more solutions to this. 
Guess it's hardware issue fro RMA?
Anyone else encountered this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This has all the symptoms of a hardware issue. I would get in contact with OnePlus customer support and ask what they can do for you. Since the device is new, they will likely replace it.

Comment: did exactly that... but kind of don't want to be 2 weeks without my phone, so still looking for some other solutions, till they send me some delivery pickup label or smth...